# How to get all values of the cells under a specific column

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
ID  |   SAMPLE 1  |  SAMPLE 2  |  SAMPLE 3  |   SAMPLE 4  |  SAMPLE 5 
1   |   cell 1    |  cell 2    |  cell 3    |   cell 4    |  cell 5
2   |   cell 1    |  cell 2    |  cell 3    |   cell 4    |  cell 5
3   |   cell 1    |  cell 2    |  cell 3    |   cell 4    |  cell 5
```

For example i have that datagridview,and I would like to get all cells under **SAMPLE 5** .
How to get all values of the cells under a specific column ?
*forloop or foreach 
Because i have a condition that if the value of the cell is less than 48 it will be remove.

Q1:How to get all values of the cells under a specific column
Q2:How to remove full row of the  cell with less 48 value

for example if under **SAMPLE 5**  has a cell with a value of 30

```
ID  |   SAMPLE 1  |  SAMPLE 2  |  SAMPLE 3  |   SAMPLE 4  |  SAMPLE 5 
1   |    Test     |   Test     |   Test     |    Test     |    30
```

the full row will be removed.

here's the code:

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgResult1.Rows)
            { 

                string regHrs = dgResult1.Rows[6].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                int regValue = 0;

                bool regCheck = int.TryParse(regHrs, out regValue);
                if ( !regCheck || Convert.ToInt32(regHrs) < 48  
                {
                    dgResult1.Rows.Remove(row);
                }
                else
                {
                    dgResult1.Rows.Remove(row);
                }


            }
```

Comment: i cant get the value of the cell .. if i can get that i want to remove the full row with the cell which is less than 48 .. but not the column ..

Answer (score 2):

Below is the sample code please go through it once

Below I have takes a datagrid and one button in winforms application. In the button click event i have written the logic.

Basically we can't remove datagrid row while it is used for loop iteration So we have saved the row numbers which has cell value < 48 and after we removed those rows.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Global variable to store the row numbers
    List<int> rowNumbers = new List<int>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();

        // Add columns to DataTable.
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("ID",typeof(int));
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("Sample 1", typeof(int));
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("Sample 2", typeof(int));


        // Add rows to the DataTable.
        myDataTable.Rows.Add(1, 10, 30);
        myDataTable.Rows.Add(2, 20, 50);
        myDataTable.Rows.Add(3, 20, 80);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = myDataTable.DefaultView;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Loop all rows
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
           //Give the column index which you want for example below i have given 3rd column index
            if (dataGridView1[2, i].Value != null)
            {
                int cellValue = (int)dataGridView1[2, i].Value;

                //Check whether the value is less than 48 or not and store the row number in one variable
                if (cellValue <= 48)
                    rowNumbers.Add(i);
            }
        }

        //Remove the rows which has the cell value < 48
        foreach (var item in rowNumbers)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<DataGridViewRow> rowsToRemove = new List<DataGridViewRow>();

int cellIndex = 0;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgResult1.Rows)
{
    string regValue = row.Cells[cellIndex].Value.ToString();
    if(...)
    {
        rowsToRemove.Add(row);
    }
}

rowsToRemove.ForEach(r=>{
   dgResult1.Rows.Remove(r);
});
```

**EDIT**

How to find column with value less than 48

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgResult1.Rows)
{
    foreach (var cell in row.Cells)
    {
        // IF Condition (less than 48)
        int columnIndex = row.Cells.IndexOf(cell);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to get the column having a cell with a less 48 value ?

Answer (score 0):

i do it like this

```
dataGridView3.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                .Select(r => r.Cells[1].Value.ToString()).ToList();
```

simply cast the rows, select the cell with the column index or name you need, you can tweak it anyway you like